# Removing characters from a 2d list

Tags: python, list, 2d, character

```
lst = [['1', 'ertt', '9', '8', '', '', '', '\n'], ['1', 'ertt', 
  '9', '', '32', '6', '0.6', '0.7\n'], ['1', 'ertt', 
  '9', '8', '', '', '', '\n'], ['1', 'ertt', '9', '', '',   
  '6.6', '', '\n'], ['1', 'ertt', '9', '', '32', '', '', '1.8\n']]
```

How can i remove the `\n` from the last column of each row. i want to keep the numbers but just remove the pesky \n?

Comment: can u show us how u got the list. beacuse it better to prevent than cure. i assume ur reading a file and splitting it

Comment: yea im reading it in, can tbe changed unfortunately

Comment: if there is just a `'\n'` in an element do you want an empty `''` element left or for that element to be removed?

Comment: yea i need the empty ' ' to be left

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply recreate the list with list comprehension, like this

```
print [item[:-1] + [item[-1].rstrip("\n")] for item in lst]
```

For every item in `lst`, we create a new list like this

```
item[:-1] + [item[-1].rstrip("\n")]
```

Here `item[:-1]` means that, everything except the last element and `item[-1]` means the last element. We simply right strip the `\n` from that.

Comment: Why create a new list? If the list is considerably large, it would be better just to change the last element.

Comment: @SukritKalra You are correct. But this is another way in which mutation is avoided.

Comment: If the OP does not need the previous list, then mutating it does not matter.

Comment: works great thx! changing the list is not an issue for my purposes

Comment: the right approach still would be stripping `\n` before splitting lines into words.

Comment: @Suor Could you please elaborate? Because I am stripping only once per line

Comment: Before multidimensional array of words, there, probably, was flat array of lines, which we could process this way: `[line.strip().split() for line in lines]` to get what we want. And, probably, even before that there was just a chunk of text, which we could just split: `text.split()`

Comment: Besides, you maybe have a bug. You can strip last word into empty string, which could be or not be ok.

Comment: @Suor `strip` is very wrong here. As per the question, OP wants to remove only the `\n` at the end of the last item. And `split`? Its not a single string, but a list of strings.

Comment: @Suor OP accepted the answer, that might hint that, this is what exactly OP wants.

Comment: ok, not `.strip()`, `.rstrip('\n')`. Anyway `\n` should be stripped from lines not from words.

Comment: @Suor Please check the question again and show me exactly which "line" has to be stripped.

Comment: @thefourtheye line not shown, but it surely in authors code. Something like `lst = [line.split() for line in lines]`.

Comment: @Suor Please quote the whatever line you are talking about, from the question.